# Mysqldump script not returning expected result after gzip output

Tags: linux, mysql

I am trying to make a script that emails the result of my mysqldump.  The successful result should be a 0, but I am getting an error code of 1.  Looks like when I pipe the results to gzip, the result changes, and I do not know how to capture only the mysqldump result.

Here is my script

```
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm")
BACKUPDIR=/backups
BPAGE=4m

mysqldump -u backup -pCih3brg4 -h localhost --all-databases | gzip > $BACKUPDIR/all_db_$DATE.sql.gz

EXITCODE=$?
if [ $EXITCODE -eq 0 ] ; then

    chmod 600 $BACKUPDIR/all_db_$DATE.sql.gz 

    find  $BACKUPDIR/ -type f -name "*.gz" -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;

    echo "DONE"

else echo "$0: backup failed with error code $?"

fi
```

Comment: Is your if statement correct?  It looks like you're treating _non_-zero results as successful.

Comment: I just changed the if statement to equals.  I am testing by changing my credentials.  Now, if it fails on dump, I get an error msg from mysql, but then it shows "DONE".

Answer (score -1):

Not answering per se, but Auto MySQL will do all of this for you, and has some other nice features.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/

I've used it for years, pretty solid.

Comment: Sorry  @Cameron, but I think this is an option out of the dilemma but not the correct answer:)